# Expo SDK 48 broke Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I have just upgraded to Expo SDK 48 and it seems I am logged out after every refresh.
I downgraded back to SDK 47, and everything works as expected.
I am using firebase v9 (v9.17.1), installed with expo install not with yarn.

Steps I followed for upgrading to Expo 48:

- Update to the latest version of EAS CLI: npm i -g eas-cli.
- Install the new version of the Expo package: yarn add expo@^48.0.0
- Upgrade all dependencies to match SDK 48: npx expo install --fix
- Check for any possibly issues in your project dependencies: npx
  expo-doctor
- Upgraded to the latest version of the firebase web sdk: expo install firebase
- delete node modules, yarn.lock and reinstall everything

What am I missing ?

I could't find anything on the release notes that can help me.

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found out anything?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately no, not yet.

Comment: If you delete `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` and reinstall your dependencies, you risk your packages possibly getting out of sync with the Expo SDK version. If you delete them and reinstall you should rerun `npx expo-doctor` afterwards

Comment: Wodin, I already mentioned doing that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I found the problem. Firebase uses a deprecated version of AsyncStorage, which apparently was removed in SDK 48.

I was able to fix it (more testing is ongoing) with this:

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

import {getReactNativePersistence, initializeAuth} from 'firebase/auth/react-native';

initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage);
});
```

With the `persistence` node, you tell Firebase to use the "native" AsyncStorage, i.e. the AsyncStorage that is present in current RN apps.

Comment: Can confirm, this solved the problem in our app.

Comment: can also confirm, this solved the problem
see also: https://amanhimself.dev/blog/remove-asyncstorage-has-been-extracted-warning-using-firebase/

Comment: Expo didn't remove AsyncStorage.....RN did.  AsyncStorage has been deprecated for a while now.  I guess the upgrade of RN in SDK 48 has finally removed it (Good!  No more deprecation warnings!   )

Comment: @GregFenton yeah, finally I can remove that YellowBox warning suppression  (tried to use `getReactNativePersistence` some months ago, but could not get it to work..)

Comment: Hi, after doing so how do i check to see if user exists?

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thanks Jonas for the help.

Comment: I fixed this in my app the way mentioned here, and it seemed to work, however some users are complaining of auth sessions only lasting until the app is closed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code where you are capturing the login event (`onAuthStateChanged()`) and how you are caching its results (typically by setting the `user` value in a state variable) and see how your app is behaving when code refreshes are happening.

My bet is that this might be a behaviour change in how Expo 48 (or more likely its underlying React or React-Native version) has, but that it isn't "wrong".  Instead, my bet is that your code was "working" under pre-48 but that it wasn't/isn't actually correct.

Consider posting some code around where/how you are calling onAuthStateChanged(), and how you are using the value returned by it to render your UI.

Comment: I experimented by setting `debugger` statements around `onAuthStateChanged`, and it seems that Firebase always considers the user to not be logged in, after each app refresh. The problem seems to be that Firebase does not have a working persistence backend, see my answer.